# German Visa application

Tags: visas, germany, applications

I am planning to visit my boyfriend in June for three months, however my biggest problem is proving that I have a reason to come back. I recently completed my studies in Hotel Reception and was employed at the same company I did my internship, but my contract is only until 31 May 2013,and thereafter I'll be leaving for Germany. My question is ... how do I prove that I have a reason to come back to South Africa besides family ?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you are a holder of South African passport, and your boyfriend lives in Germany?

Comment: Do you actually have any reason to go back? Only as you've described it, you sound like quite a high risk case for just staying... So you're likely going to need to work hard to prove otherwise!

Comment: If you are single, do not have a lot of savings or dont have a high income, do not have sufficient family ties (and only God knows how various embassies judge that), and if you are not going with the sole purpose of tourism, I can *almost* bet, you ain't getting that visa.

Comment: You can not . Options :  1-  Do you have any listed assets ? ( car, house, monetary ? )  2 . Get another contract for the period when you are back. 3. Or a letter from some company saying that you have a secure job when returning. ( ask a friend that runs a company .. ). And Don't mention the boyfriend , it will put you in High risk.  Just say a colleague or a friend .

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [full rules](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/Visabestimmungen_node.html#doc480844bodyText7):

> The mission must ensure that the following requirements have been met
>   in each individual case:
>
> 1. The purpose of the trip to Germany must be plausible and comprehensible.
> 2. The applicant must be in a position to finance his/her living and travel costs from his/her own funds or income.
> 3. The visa holder must be prepared to leave the Schengen area before the visa expires.
> 4. Documentary evidence must be provided of travel health insurance with a minimum coverage of 30,000 euro valid for the entire Schengen
>      area.
>
> Should an applicant be unable to prove that he/she can finance the
>   journey and stay from his/her own funds, a third person may undertake
>   to cover all costs associated with the trip in accordance with
>   sections 66 and 68 of the Residence Act.

For 1, a written invitation from your boyfriend and proof of his residency status should be sufficient. I'll assume that 2 and 4 are straightforward as well. That leaves 3 as the main hurdle. According to [this website](http://www.juraportal24.de/auslaender-_und_asylrecht/artikel_1500/besuchervisum%3a_voraussetzungen_fuer_die_erteilung_durch_die_deutsche_botschaft.html), embassies will typically require proof of family ties and sufficient income.

The best option I can think of would be to already secure a job (i.e. employment contract) for the time after your return from Germany.